# Как создать Generic метод для проверки типов

Tags: java, generics

Всем привет.

Нужно создать метод , который бы принимал любой экземпляр обьекта!

Возможно ли написать метод который бы принимал и обрабатывал во время компиляции любой тип который он получит ?

```
 public static void main (String [] strings){

    inspector(new User("Kostia","Kostia000","Kostia..Kostikrus90@gmail.com"));
    inspector(new Message("",""));
    // And more beans

}

    public static void inspector(Object object) {

    if(!(object.equals(null))){

        if(object instanceof User){ // Make only one method and one check for instance to all incoming type of object instances!

            Converter<User> typeConverter = new Converter<User>();
            User user = typeConverter.convertTo(object);
            System.out.print(user.toString());

        }
    }
}

public class Converter<T> {

protected T convertTo(Object type){
    return (T) type;
  }
}
```

Comment: Фраза «*любой экземпляр объекта*» некорректна. Объект – это экземпляр какого-либо конкретного типа. Вы, очевидно, имели ввиду «*объекта произвольного типа*».

Comment: А смысл-то, смысл в чем? ;)

Comment: Обучение .. ознакомления с generics..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как создать Generic метод для проверки типов?

Например, так:

```
public <T> boolean compareTypes(T firstObject, T secondObject) {
    return firstObject.getClass().equals(secondObject.getClass());
}
```